# Flutter Tab Bar View

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I'm relatively new to Flutter and am stuck on a Tab Bar issue.

I've created this tab bar on a pop-up container. I'd like the tab bar itself to remain in place, with the content scrolling beneath it. However, in my current version the **whole section** (incl. tab bar options) gets pushed beneath the text container above.

How can I keep this fixed? I've looked into SliverAppBars, but I don't need a full app bar in place, just the tab bar.

Code below - with a focus on the NestedScrollView section. Any help greatly appreciated!

```
class TokenTabs extends StatefulWidget {
  const TokenTabs({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TokenTabs> createState() => _TokenTabsState();
}

class _TokenTabsState extends State<TokenTabs>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late int currentTab;
  late TabController tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    currentTab = 1;
    tabController = TabController(length: 3, vsync: this, initialIndex: 1);
    tabController.animation!.addListener(() {
      final value = tabController.animation!.value.round();
      if (value != currentTab && mounted) {
        changePage(value);
      }
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  void changePage(int newTab) {
    setState(() {
      currentTab = newTab;
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    tabController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Color unselectedColor = Colors.grey;

    return NestedScrollView(
      headerSliverBuilder: (context, value) {
        return [
          SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border(
                  bottom: BorderSide(
                      width: 0.1, color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5)),
                ),
              ),
              height: 45,
              child: TabBar(
                controller: tabController,
                indicator: UnderlineTabIndicator(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                  color: Colors.orange,
                  width: 3,
                )),
                indicatorPadding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(6.0, 0.0, 6.0, 0.0),
                tabs: [
                  Text(
                    'Posts',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight:
                          currentTab == 0 ? FontWeight.bold : FontWeight.normal,
                      fontSize: 16.0,
                      color: currentTab == 0 ? Colors.black : unselectedColor,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    'Holders',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight:
                          currentTab == 1 ? FontWeight.bold : FontWeight.normal,
                      fontSize: 16.0,
                      color: currentTab == 1 ? Colors.black : unselectedColor,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    'Rewards',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight:
                          currentTab == 2 ? FontWeight.bold : FontWeight.normal,
                      fontSize: 16.0,
                      color: currentTab == 2 ? Colors.black : unselectedColor,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ];
      },
      body: Container(
        child: TabBarView(
          controller: tabController,
          children: const [
            Text('Posts of users'),
            Text('Other holders'),
            Text('Rewards unlocked'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: I need this bar to remain in place]

[image: But it's hidden upon scrolling up]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved this - just used DefaultTabController instead:

```
 return DefaultTabController(
      length: 3,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            height: 40,
            child: TabBar(
              controller: tabController,
              indicator: UnderlineTabIndicator(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                color: Colors.orange,
                width: 3,
              )),
              indicatorPadding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(6.0, 0.0, 6.0, 0.0),
              tabs: [
                Text(
                  'Posts',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight:
                        currentTab == 0 ? FontWeight.bold : FontWeight.normal,
                    fontSize: 16.0,
                    color: currentTab == 0 ? Colors.black : unselectedColor,
                  ),
                ),
                Text(
                  'Holders',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight:
                        currentTab == 1 ? FontWeight.bold : FontWeight.normal,
                    fontSize: 16.0,
                    color: currentTab == 1 ? Colors.black : unselectedColor,
                  ),
                ),
                Text(
                  'Rewards',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight:
                        currentTab == 2 ? FontWeight.bold : FontWeight.normal,
                    fontSize: 16.0,
                    color: currentTab == 2 ? Colors.black : unselectedColor,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: TabBarView(
              controller: tabController,
              children: [
                ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: 100,
                    itemBuilder: (_, int index) {
                      return Text('Index $index');
                    }),
                ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: 100,
                    itemBuilder: (_, int index) {
                      return Text('Index $index');
                    }),
                ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: 100,
                    itemBuilder: (_, int index) {
                      return Text('Index $index');
                    }),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Comment: You should mark this as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can read the following article on Flutter tab bar views. hope it helps
https://daniasblog.com/flutter-tabbar-gradient-style/

Comment: Thanks for pointing me towards your blog - but I still can't figure out how to keep the TabBar fixed without having it as part of the app bar. Can you advise on how best to tackle this in the code above?