# How to Create This Tab View in Flutter with SyncFusion? What is the Name of the Widget?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web, syncfusion

I am trying to create this kind of tab view but I am so confused what the name of the widget is in Flutter and SyncFusion. I want to create this chart with 2 tab, the first tab is voltage chart and the second one is current chart. Thank you.

Here's the picture:
[image: Tab View]

Here's my current code:

```
@override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          drawer: const SideMenu(),
          body: FutureBuilder(
              future: getData2(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                  return const Loading();
                } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return Text(snapshot.hasError.toString());
                } else {
                  final themeChange = Provider.of<DarkThemeProvider>(context);
                  return SafeArea(
                    child: Row(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        if (Responsive.isDesktop(context))
                          const Expanded(
                            child: SideMenu(),
                          ),
                        Expanded(
                          flex: 5,
                          child: SingleChildScrollView(
                            primary: false,
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(defaultPadding),
                            child: Column(
                              children: [
                                Container(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(defaultPadding),
                                  child: const Header(),
                                ),
                                const SizedBox(height: defaultPadding),
                                Container(
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    color: themeChange.darkTheme
                                        ? secondaryColor
                                        : quarterColor,
                                    borderRadius:
                                        const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                                  ),
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(defaultPadding),
                                  child: DefaultTabController(
                                    length: 2,
                                    child: Column(
                                      children: [
                                        SizedBox(
                                          height: 40.0,
                                          child: TabBar(
                                            controller: _tabController,
                                            indicator: const UnderlineTabIndicator(
                                              borderSide: BorderSide(
                                                color: Colors.yellow,
                                                width: 3.0,
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                            indicatorPadding:
                                                const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                                            tabs: const [
                                              Text(
                                                'Voltages Chart',
                                              ),
                                              Text(
                                                'Currents Chart',
                                              ),
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Expanded(
                                  child: TabBarView(
                                    controller: _tabController,
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      ListView.builder(
                                        itemCount: 100,
                                        itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
                                          return const DwpVoltageCharts();
                                        },
                                      ),
                                      ListView.builder(
                                        itemCount: 100,
                                        itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
                                          return const DwpCurrentCharts();
                                        },
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                                const SizedBox(height: defaultPadding),
                                Container(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(defaultPadding),
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    color: themeChange.darkTheme
                                        ? secondaryColor
                                        : quarterColor,
                                    borderRadius:
                                        const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                                  ),
                                  child: const Center(
                                    child: PowerChart(),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                }
              }),
        );
      }
    }
```

Please this is my currents code and I don't know how to make it works because I am really new about it. Thank You.

Comment: have you tried TabBarView

Comment: I haven't try it yet. Currently I only find tutorials talking about TabBar and PageView. Thank you for your suggestions I'll try it, really appreciate it bro.

Comment: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/design/tabs check this documentation i hope it will help you

Comment: I have tried it, but it seems throw an error. I looked at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71661568/flutter-tab-bar-view but in my codes it doesn't work. Can you provide me another example? I have try read the documentation, but it does not help. Thank You.

Comment: can you share the code i will try to help you

Comment: Be aware that the SyncFusion products in the Dart/Flutter pub are *not* open source.  They are released under a commercial license that may subject you or your organization to a financial liability, and might affect downstream re-users of your code.

Comment: I already update the questions bro, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve your requirement using the [DefaultTabController](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DefaultTabController-class.html), [TabBar](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TabBar-class.html) and [TabBarView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TabBarView-class.html) widgets available in the flutter framework. We have created a simple sample in which we have achieved your requirement to switch between two tabs to view the voltage and current chart and attached the sample below for reference.

Sample: https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/i407342-45112383